# How to filter rows in pandas based on row numeric values

Tags: python, python-3.x, select, filter, numbers

i have a dataframe like this:

```
         mcnfecha  mcnnumedoc   mcncuenta
0      2015-12-31         1.0    14353605
96     2015-12-31         7.0    15400505
97     2015-12-31         7.0    15920505
98     2015-12-31         7.0    41351005
99     2015-12-31         7.0    41352150
100    2015-12-31         7.0    41352151
101    2015-12-31         7.0    15922005
95     2015-12-31         7.0    15281005
102    2015-12-31         7.0    15922010
104    2015-12-31         7.0    21050505
105    2015-12-31         7.0    21051004
106    2015-12-31         7.0    21051007
107    2015-12-31         7.0    21051008
```

i want to keep all the rows in the column 'mcncuenta' which starts by 4135.

How could i do this??

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**`astype(str)`** with **`startswith`**

```
df.loc[df.mcncuenta.astype(str).str.startswith('4135')]

# Result
       mcnfecha  mcnnumedoc  mcncuenta
98   2015-12-31         7.0   41351005
99   2015-12-31         7.0   41352150
100  2015-12-31         7.0   41352151
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! it worked perfectly, it was easy enough but i wasn't capable to see it. I appreciate the help :)